# Symfony Expected argument of type "?App\Entity\ProductPriceOptions", "string" given

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

my problem would look like the following.

I tried to create a form where you can select the packaging of the product you need and then upload it to the shopping cart when you have it, but there is a problem with this code

Controller:

```
`$add_cart_item = new ShoppingCart();
        $add_cart_item_form = $this->createFormBuilder($add_cart_item)
            ->add('ProductPriceOption', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => $show_price_options])

            ->add('ProductTransportOption', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => $show_delivery_options])

            ->add('Order', SubmitType::class, [
                'label' => 'Add cart_'])
            ->getForm();


        $add_cart_item_form->handleRequest($request);
        if($add_cart_item_form->isSubmitted() && $add_cart_item_form->isValid()){
            $entityManager->persist($add_cart_item);

            $add_cart_item->setUser($user->getId());
            $add_cart_item->setProduct($prod_id);

            $entityManager->flush();
        }`
```

Shopping cart entity:

```
`namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ShoppingCartRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ShoppingCartRepository::class)]
class ShoppingCart
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private $id;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: User::class, inversedBy: 'shoppingCarts')]
    private $user;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'smallint')]
    private $Productpiece;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Product::class, inversedBy: 'shoppingCarts')]
    private $Product;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: ProductPriceOptions::class, inversedBy: 'shoppingCarts')]
    private $ProductPriceOption;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: ProductTransportOptions::class, inversedBy: 'shoppingCarts')]
    private $ProductTransportOption;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getUser(): ?User
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function setUser(?User $user): self
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getProductpiece(): ?int
    {
        return $this->productpiece;
    }

    public function setProductpiece(int $productpiece): self
    {
        $this->productpiece = $productpiece;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getProduct(): ?Product
    {
        return $this->Product;
    }

    public function setProduct(?Product $Product): self
    {
        $this->Product = $Product;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getProductPriceOption(): ?ProductPriceOptions
    {
        return $this->ProductPriceOption;
    }

    public function setProductPriceOption(?ProductPriceOptions $ProductPriceOption): self
    {
        $this->ProductPriceOption = $ProductPriceOption;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getProductTransportOption(): ?ProductTransportOptions
    {
        return $this->ProductTransportOption;
    }

    public function setProductTransportOption(?ProductTransportOptions $ProductTransportOption): self
    {
        $this->ProductTransportOption = $ProductTransportOption;

        return $this;
    }
}`
```

The problem may be due to data transfers.
Now the generated form contains the data of an openable array and the package can be selected from among them. But for some reason the format doesn't meet the requirements.

Comment: Try changing the ChoiceType and use the [EntityType](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html) instead as it is a ManyToOne entity.

Answer (score 0):

Use EntityType instead of ChoiceType

```
 ->add('ProductPriceOption', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => ProductPriceOption::class])
```

Otherwise if you want to to use ChoiceType, you need to get the  ProductPriceOption object in the controller

```
 if($add_cart_item_form->isSubmitted() && $add_cart_item_form->isValid()){
        
        $productPriceOptionId = $add_cart_item_form->get("ProductPriceOption")->getData();
        $productPriceOption = $entityManager->getRepository(ProductPriceOption::class)->findOneBy(['id' => $productPriceOptionId]);
        
        $add_cart_item->setProductPriceOption($productPriceOption);

        //Use the same logic with setUser and setProduct using EntityType or getting the object in the controller
        //$add_cart_item->setUser($user->getId()); //ERROR
        //$add_cart_item->setProduct($prod_id); //ERROR
        $entityManager->persist($add_cart_item);
        $entityManager->flush();
    }`
```